# app service's scm portal: why is it down and how to turn it back up

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

My app service's scm portal is down, even though the app service is running itself. To identify the issue, I followed this post: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/424716/cannot-deploy-my-app-service-kudu-down-503.html by going to https://resources.azure.com/ to find my app service, and can verify that:

```
"state": "Running",
"scmSiteAlsoStopped": false
```

Does anyone know why the scm portal would be down and how to bring it back up?

Comment: Restart your app service and check once.